# C# - how to do encoding on string or char?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, encoding, character-encoding

I'm reading metadata from specific bytes in files but the results I get have no encoding. I would like to encode them to Encoding.Default for readability.

How do I convert either full Unicode string or at least a single char?

C# .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myByteArray);
```

Would that work?

Comment: Probably not, utf-16 isn't very likely.  Could happen though.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *encode* bytes to a particular encoding - you *decode* them from the original encoding. You have to use the *right* encoding to use - you can't just pick it arbitrarily.

Do these bytes actually represent text data? If so, what encoding do the already use? This should be part of the file format.

If they're *not* actually encoded text, but you want a reliable text representation of arbitrary binary data, use `Convert.ToBase64String`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the namespace System.Text.Encoding :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesToGetStringFrom, 0, bytesToGetStringFrom.Length);

There are "encodings" other than UTF8.

Comment: Noticing Jon's comment, it is decoding, which is why "encoding" is in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

use somthing like this

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetChars(pass your byte array here)
```